# Ionic navigation state.go shows previous view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic and trying to create a app. The issue I am having is that when I navigate to a new state, by using:

```
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.navigate = function(path) {
        $state.go(path);
    };
})
```

It navigates to my new view / template but also shows the previous template which I navigated from above the new template. Pictures attached to demonstrate the issue.

Theese are my routes

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/auth/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })

    .state('signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        templateUrl: 'views/auth/signup.html',
        controller: 'signupCtrl'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Controllers

```
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.navigate = function(path) {
        $state.go(path);
    };
})

.controller('signupCtrl', function() {})
.controller('loginCtrl', function() {})
```

and my button calling the new state:

```
<button ng-click="navigate('signup')">let's sign up!</button>
```

[View one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6UtL.jpg)

[View two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6vLf.jpg)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Where you are calling "appCtrl" ?

if "appCtrl" is a main control, you have to change stateprovider like this;

```
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
         .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'views/auth/master.html',
            controller: 'appCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/auth/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })

        .state('app.signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: 'views/auth/signup.html',
            controller: 'signupCtrl'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    });
```

Comment: Hey. I'm using the appCtrl in my index.html only, as:  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">, so i'm not calling it through a stateprovider.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `$location.path`?

```
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.navigate = function(path) {
        $location.path(path);
    };
})
```

Where the value of path is the value of URL of your `$stateProvider`